# hibernate envers and ordered lists

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, hibernate-envers

I've been using Hibernate Envers 3.6 quite happily for some time. 
 However I've come across an issue with ordered lists which seems to cause Envers to fail.

We have a class A with a List of B, mapped one-to-many in 
 e.g., in class A

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "A", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<B> getB() {
    return this.B;
}
```

When I retrieve a revision, I load up the appropriate instance of A, then explicitly initialize the collection of Bs: E.g.,

```
for (B b: rvision.getB()){
   b.getClass();// init  fields
}
```

Recently though we needed to add an 'orderColumn' annotation on the getB() method to ensure consistent ordering of the list in the DB.

E.g.,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "A", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 @OrderColumn(name="columnIndex")
    public List<B> getB() {
        return this.B;
    }
```

This completely breaks the collection initialization in Envers, failing with a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.ListCollectionInitializor.addToCollection(ListCollectionInitializor.java:81)
at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.ListCollectionInitializor.addToCollection(ListCollectionInitializor.java:39)
at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.initializor.AbstractCollectionInitializor.initialize(AbstractCollectionInitializor.java:67)
at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.checkInit(CollectionProxy.java:50)
at org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.lazy.proxy.CollectionProxy.size(CollectionProxy.java:55)
etc....
```

We have isolated this into a unit test; toggling the OrderColumn annotation is sufficient to cause this problem. The OrderColumn is working fine with regular Hibernate.

The problem seems to stem from line 47 of org.hibernate.envers.entities.mapper.relation.component.MiddleSimpleComponentMapper:

```
 return ((Map<String, Object>) data.get(verEntCfg.getOriginalIdPropName())).get(propertyName);
```

Basically the 'propertyName' it's looking for is called 'mapKey' and the lookup returns null when it shouldn't. This isn't a property of my objects so it must be some internal Envers property.

If anyone have a clue what is going on, I'd be very grateful!
Thanks
 Richard

Comment: Just to add, with an @OrderBy annnotation instead, Envers initializes the B collection OK without error

Comment: There's one test in Envers with an (at)OrderColumn (see links below). Though it uses (at)ManyToMany. Any chances to try your test with latest Hibernate? (4.1)

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-envers/src/test/java/org/hibernate/envers/test/entities/manytomany/unidirectional/M2MIndexedListTargetNotAuditedEntity.java

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-envers/src/test/java/org/hibernate/envers/test/integration/manytomany/unidirectional/M2MIndexedListNotAuditedTarget.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ran into this issue with Hibernate Envers 4.x.  The solution for us was to use the `@AuditMappedBy` annotation to identify the order column for Envers. As shown in the example [here](http://www.solewing.org/blog/2015/07/hibernate-envers-onetomany-list-and-ordercolumn/) it is necessary to map the order column value into a field on the referenced entity to make it all work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue a few weeks ago.

I just added the @MapKey annotation Envers was looking for, and so far I haven't seen any further issues.